# Will Lidar see a fence?

Tags: mobile-robot, mapping, lidar

I am looking at the possibility of using LIDAR to do obstacle avoidance for a robotics project I am working on but the project involves avoiding a chain link fence. Has anyone used LIDAR to detect fences and if so how well did it work? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience depending on the point density and the distance to the fence you will see noise where the fence is but it will be far from a flat wall.

You can do some basic math, finding the width of a square in your fence and taking that over the width of the wire used in the fence. you can find the probability of a lidar point "hitting" the fence.

Divide by the total number of points pointed toward the fence, and you can get a rough idea of how many returns from the fence you will get.

If you predict around 10 that would probably be far too small to get a good return, shoot for at least 100-300 depending on what you are trying to achieve.